# No response when running pycoingecko CoinGeckoAPI

Tags: python, api, coingecko

I do not receive any error after running the code, but there are also no response. Let me know if any other information is required to figure where went wrong.

Input

```
from pycoingecko import CoinGeckoAPI

cg = CoinGeckoAPI()

cg.ping()

cg.get_price(ids='bitcoin', vs_currencies='usd')
```

Output

```
aikenong@Aikens-MacBook-Air ~ % /usr/local/bin/python3 "/Users/aikenong/Desktop/crypto charts/charts.py"
aikenong@Aikens-MacBook-Air ~ %
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to use print command before the ping request.
I had the same problem using CoinGeckoAPI. I tried to run my script in Jupyter Notebook and saw that I received the output there, so I tried to use `print(cg.ping())` and it finally displayed in the terminal. Although, I still don't understand how it really works.

Hope that helps you. :)